# Autoscaling EC2 instances running Nginx-based web service behind ELB

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling

Looking for advice on the recommended way of setting up autoscaling for a pair of EC2 instances running a Nginx-based web service behind an ELB.

I understand that I'll need to use CloudWatch to monitor my EC2 instances - is it sufficient to save my EC2 instance as an AMI image and then have CloudWatch fire up new instances using that image (with ELB automatically routing requests in round-robin fashion to available instances)?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach your load balancer to your Auto Scaling Group (ASG). When attached, the load balancer automatically registers the newly launched instances in the group and distributes the traffic across them. For adding health checks to the ASG with a load balancer attached to it, you need to:

1. Go to EC2 console
2. Choose **Auto Scaling Group** under **Auto Scaling**
3. Select your group and click **Actions** and then **Edit**
4. Select `ELB` for **Health Check Type** and set the period (e.g. 300)
5. Save

Note that an ASG with `EC2` health check type will not automatically replace the unhealthy instances. Read more [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-add-elb-healthcheck.html).

Comment: Thank you. One thing that still confuses me though is that there seems to be two alternate ways of having an autoscaled web service running on EC2 instances behind an ELB: A) create an Auto Scaling Launch Config that specifies the image id of my custom AMI (and the instance type to use). Then, when the Auto Scaling trigger is triggered, it will simply spin up new EC2 instances using that AMI.  B) Use ELB and ECS instead as ECS seems to have its own Auto Scaling feature.  In what circumstances is it better to use ECS?

Comment: According to the documentation, containers are optimal for running small, decoupled services. So it really depends on what you want to achieve.